# How do I find out if a program uses GTK 2 or 3?

Tags: gtk, inkscape

Thinking of trying to tweak a theme to get Inkscape more compact. Was wondering if there was a way to tell which version of GTK+ it uses?

Comment: What if it is an uncompiled python program (gaupol, for example). Ldd says `not a dynamic executable`.

Comment: @sup Perhaps looking at the dependencies via `apt-cache depends <package> | grep gtk` is an alternative for such uncompiled program, including `firefox`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ldd`. Mine appears to use gtk2 libraries.

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/inkscape | grep gtk
    libgtkmm-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1 (0x00007fa8de4d5000)
    libgtkspell.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgtkspell.so.0 (0x00007fa8dcfe1000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa8dc9a7000)
```

Answer (score 4):

Inkscape currently uses GTK2. Inkscape trunk has the ability to compile against GTK3, however that is a work-in-progress and is far less compact than when built against GTK2 (GTK3 was created with touchscreen support in mind, so widgets are larger).

-an Inkscape dev

Comment: Thank you. I find on my laptop (1366x768) that I'm always short of space for the dockable stuff (layers,  fill, etc.) and Gnome is very fond of huge toy-town style buttons! Of course Adobe take it too far and give you 4px click zones. KDE apps strike a more effective balance, IMO, but then I sort of fell out with KDE after 3.5. Anyway, thank you for your useful information.