# Can I change the theme for only one program in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, themes, icon-themes

I want to change the theme that Inkscape uses to a dark one, but I want the rest of the programs I use to retain the theme they currently have.

I found this article (http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/setting-a-custom-gtk-theme-for-specific-applications/) but it seems to be outdated and doesn't work for me.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and the version of inkscape I'm trying to apply a different theme to is 0.48.4. I can change the theme of inkscape by changing the global theme using unity tweak tool, but then all other programs change too.

Also, if there's any way to change the icon set for a specific application, I would like to do that as well.

Answer (score 4):

See [How can one make Firefox ignore my GTK theme entirely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8336/how-can-one-make-firefox-ignore-my-gtk-theme-entirely) for how to make `gtk2` applications like Firefox or LibreOffice have distinct themes.

[How do I find out if a program uses GTK 2 or 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160469/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-program-uses-gtk-2-or-3) indicates that Inkscape is a `gtk2` application.

For `gtk3` applications, if your system's GTK3 version is higher than 3.10, you can use the GTK_THEME environment variable like this:

```
GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark gnome-calculator
```

I don't know about `qt` applications.

---

I use this script to launch LibreOffice with its own theme:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Numix/gtk-2.0/gtkrc libreoffice --calc
```

Comment: I just tried that, however inkscape still used the same theme as the rest of my system, despite me setting the variable to a different theme. Is it possible that the setting is being overwritten by something?

Comment: Did you log out and log back in?

Comment: And is Inkscape still gtk2 or is it now gtk3?

Comment: It appears to be gtk2. And is there a reason that logging off and back on would help? I'm just trying to change the environmental variable before I launch inkscape, not any global settings. I'll try logging off and back on when I get the chance, but I don't think it will make a difference.

Comment: See if the script I added works after you fix it for your theme and program. No need for log out.

Comment: Well, it half works. It's changing parts of inkscape but not everything it changes if I apply the theme globally using unity tweak tool. It doesn't change the window frame or the scroll bar popups or most of the UI elements, just some of the background colors.